# I am trying to label a grouped-bar chart in R and cannot seem to get the coding down

Tags: r, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart. Right now this is what I have:

[Grouped Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR5dN.jpg)

For background: I have quite a large data set with multiple variables. What I am interested in for this bar chart is visually representing the median inspection distance (cm) that male guppies (yes, fish) will inspect a predator in the presence and absence of females. As you can see, below the two bar charts there is "A" and "B".... I want these to say "Bright" and "Drab"... I cannot seem to get anything to work!!

this is my code right now:

```
barplot(matrix(c(18.41,7.20,21.40,11.17),nr=2), beside=T, 
     col=c("aquamarine3","snow3"), ylim=c(0, 25), 
     names.arg=LETTERS[1:2], xlab = "Colour", ylab = "Inspection Frequency (cm)")  
legend("topright", c("Present","Absent"), pch=15, col=c("aquamarine3","snow3"), 
    bty="n")
```

thank you in advance - I know this is a super basic question but I am fairly new at this!

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the plotting of the x axis labels and then add labels of your own. To see where barplot draws each of the bars, save it to an object.

```
myplot <- barplot(matrix(c(18.41,7.20,21.40,11.17),nr=2), 
 beside=T, xaxt="n",
 col=c("aquamarine3","snow3"), ylim=c(0, 25), 
 names.arg=LETTERS[1:2], xlab = "Colour", 
 ylab = "Inspection Frequency (cm)") 

axis( 1, at=colMeans(myplot), labels=c("Bright","Drab"))
```